# Pig Latin Translator - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So for my cit class I have to write a pig Latin converter program and I'm really confused on how to use arrays and strings together. 
The rules for the conversion are simple, you just move the first letter of the word to the back and then add ay. ex: hell in English would be ellhay in pig Latin
I have this so far:

```
<form name="form">
<p>English word/sentence:</p> <input type="text" id="english" required="required" size="80" /> <br />
<input type="button" value="Translate!" onClick="translation()" />
<p>Pig Latin translation:</p> <textarea name="piglat" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
fucntion translation() { 
var delimiter = " ";
    input = document.form.english.value;
    tokens = input.split(delimiter);
    output = [];
    len = tokens.length;
    i;

for (i = 1; i<len; i++){
    output.push(input[i]);
}
output.push(tokens[0]);
output = output.join(delimiter);
}
//-->
</script>
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: The first step to solving the problem is learning to ask the right question. What *exactly* is confusing to you? You might just find you that you find the tools to answer your own question.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but note that you're creating *global* variables for `input`, `tokens`, `output`, `len`, and `i` in your `translation` function (the word `fucntion` [sic] is also misspelled, but at least you'll get an error for that in the console). You've declared `delimiter` using `var`, but the `;` at the end of that ends the `var` statement, so the following several statements are just assignments (except for `i;`) in which you fall prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Just FWIW.

Comment: @32bitkid I'm confused on how to move letters around in an array I guess.. I know how to separate the first letter from the word but not how to move it at the end

Comment: Please var all of your variables.. we dont want global scope hoarding

Comment: @Gcap: There's no need to move letters in an array. Once you have the array of strings for the words, which you're correctly getting (other than the things in my note above) from `split`, look at using [`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Thanks T.J. i appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I couldn't help myself, but here is a one-liner to translate a whole paragraph/sentence or whatever... `'Hello world, how are you?'.replace(/([a-z])([a-z]*)([^a-z]*)/gi,'$2$1ay$3')` http://regex101.com/r/yJ8pL3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the two things you really need to be looking at are the `substring()` method and string concatentation (adding two strings together) in general. Being that all of the objects in the array returned from your call to `split()` are strings, simple string concatentation works fine. For example, using these two methods, you could move the first letter of a string to the end with something like this:

```
var myString = "apple";

var newString = mystring.substring(1) + mystring.substring(0,1);
```

Comment: I was also wondering how to keep outputs saved in the textarea box.. say I type in "are" and in the textarea it translates it to "reaay" and then I type in "hello" the textarea should output "ellohay" and "reaay" under it.. do you think you could help me out with that too?

Comment: Tip: `.substring(0, 1) === .charAt(0)`

Answer (score 5):

```
function translate(str) {
     str=str.toLowerCase();
     var n =str.search(/[aeiuo]/);
     switch (n){
       case 0: str = str+"way"; break;
       case -1: str = str+"ay"; break;
       default :
         //str= str.substr(n)+str.substr(0,n)+"ay";
         str=str.replace(/([^aeiou]*)([aeiou])(\w+)/, "$2$3$1ay");
       break;
    }
    return str;

}


 translate("paragraphs")
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is basic, but it works.  First, take care of the words that start with vowels.  Otherwise, for words that start with one or more consonants, determine the number of consonants and move them to the end.

```
function translate(str) {
    str=str.toLowerCase();

    // for words that start with a vowel:
    if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].indexOf(str[0]) > -1) {
        return str=str+"way";
    }

    // for words that start with one or more consonants
   else {
   //check for multiple consonants
       for (var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){
           if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].indexOf(str[i]) > -1){
               var firstcons = str.slice(0, i);
               var middle = str.slice(i, str.length);
               str = middle+firstcons+"ay";
               break;}
            }
    return str;}
}

translate("school");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're struggling with arrays this might be a bit complicated, but it's concise and compact:

```
var toPigLatin = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/(^\w)(.+)/, '$2$1ay');
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/2ERmg/

Slightly improved version to use with whole sentences:

```
var toPigLatin = function(str){
    return str.replace(/\b(\w)(\w+)\b/g, '$2$1ay');
};
```

Comment: on what browser are you testing? It works fine for me in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var newStr = str;
  // if string starts with vowel make 'way' adjustment
  if (newStr.slice(0,1).match(/[aeiouAEIOU]/)) {
    newStr = newStr + "way";
  }
  // else, iterate through first consonents to find end of cluster
  // move consonant cluster to end, and add 'ay' adjustment
  else {
    var moveLetters = "";
    while (newStr.slice(0,1).match(/[^aeiouAEIOU]/)) {
      moveLetters += newStr.slice(0,1);
      newStr = newStr.slice(1, newStr.length);
    }
    newStr = newStr + moveLetters + "ay";
  }
  return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, using a separate function as a true or false switch.

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {

  // returns true only if the first letter in str is a vowel
  function isVowelFirstLetter() {
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'];
    for (i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
      if (vowels[i] === str[0]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  // if str begins with vowel case
  if (isVowelFirstLetter()) {
    str += 'way';
  }
  else {
    // consonants to move to the end of string
    var consonants = '';

    while (isVowelFirstLetter() === false) {
      consonants += str.slice(0,1);
      // remove consonant from str beginning
      str = str.slice(1);
    }

    str += consonants + 'ay';
  }

  return str;
}

translatePigLatin("jstest");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution code :

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
var vowel;
var consonant;
var n =str.charAt(0);
vowel=n.match(/[aeiou]/g);
if(vowel===null)
{
consonant= str.slice(1)+str.charAt(0)+”ay”;
}
else
{
consonant= str.slice(0)+”way”;
}
var regex = /[aeiou]/gi;
var vowelIndice = str.indexOf(str.match(regex)[0]);
if (vowelIndice>=2)
{
consonant = str.substr(vowelIndice) + str.substr(0, vowelIndice) + ‘ay’;
}

return consonant;
}

translatePigLatin(“gloove”);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way.

```
String.prototype.toPigLatin = function()
{
    var str = "";
    this.toString().split(' ').forEach(function(word)
    {
        str += (toPigLatin(word) + ' ').toString();
    });
    return str.slice(0, -1);
};

function toPigLatin(word)
{
    //Does the word already start with a vowel?
    if(word.charAt(0).match(/a*e*i*o*u*A*E*I*O*U*/g)[0])
    {
        return word;
    }

    //Match Anything before the firt vowel.
    var front = word.match(/^(?:[^a?e?i?o?u?A?E?I?O?U?])+/g);
    return (word.replace(front, "") + front + (word.match(/[a-z]+/g) ? 'a' : '')).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of Pig Latin:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  let vowels = /[aeiou]/g;
  var n = str.search(vowels); //will find the index of vowels
  switch (n){
    case 0:
      str = str+"way";
      break;
    case -1:
      str = str+"ay";
      break;
    default:
      str = str.slice(n)+str.slice(0,n)+"ay";
      break;
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(translatePigLatin("rhythm"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Your friends are the string function `.split`, and the array functions `.join` and `.slice` and `.concat`.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessor_methods
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML

**warning:** *Below is a complete solution you can refer to once you have finished or spent too much time.*

```
function letters(word) {
    return word.split('')
}

function pigLatinizeWord(word) {
    var chars = letters(word);
    return chars.slice(1).join('') + chars[0] + 'ay';
}

function pigLatinizeSentence(sentence) {
    return sentence.replace(/\w+/g, pigLatinizeWord)
}
```

Demo:

```
> pigLatinizeSentence('This, is a test!')
"hisTay, siay aay esttay!"
```

Comment: Using `split` to split out all the chars is overkill. Just use `substring(0, 1)` and `substring(1)`. And yes, usually best not to answer homework questions with complete solutions (not even if you put a caveat at the top).

Comment: _Technically_, **is** and **a** should be isway and away.

Comment: Thank you google for indexing these pages so profs can search for used code hehe.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: you're correct, but I get in the habit of doing so because it supports functions I often use, such as `.slice` (negative indexing from the back, not necessary here), `.filter` (find/drop letters with characteristic), `.forEach` (rather than a for-loop), `.every` (is every letter uppercase?), `.some` (is some character in a set of bad characters?), `.map` (caesar shift), `.reduce`.

Comment: @ninjagecko: I really like power drills. I use them for everything: Drilling holes in walls, pounding in nails, doing the washing up, ... ;-)