# How can I use a switch statement to create a Piglatin translator?

Tags: javascript, html, language-translation

for reference... #inp is the input id and #rsp is the paragragh i want the result to show up in.

This is just the first step of many, but I'm already stumped after significant time spent trying to figure out how to replace #rsp with the out put of the switch statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var piglatin = $('#inp').value();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        switch(piglatin){
            case piglatin.charAt(0)==='a':
                $('#rsp') = piglatin + 'ay';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the reason for doing that?

Comment: `switch (piglatin.charAt(0)) { case "a": … }`, rather…? And use `.text(newText)` or `.val(newText)` or just not jQuery

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306899/pig-latin-translator-javascript

Comment: Use shorter `$('#inp').val();` and to put it back do `$('#rsp').html(piglatin + 'ay');`

Comment: Oh, and you probably need to get the value inside your click handler and [`value` doesn’t exist](http://api.jquery.com/value) and `piglatin` should really be a function that takes and returns a string

Comment: There are several problems with your Javascript here, most notably your declaration of the `piglatin` variable at document ready instead of when the button is clicked. Also, you are using `.value()` which is a native method and will not work on jQuery objects. Use `.val()` instead to get and set the string.

Comment: Also, a JavaScript pig latin translator already exists: http://cdl.best.vwh.net/JavaScript/Latin.html

Comment: Is it really that much trouble to learn the proper form of switch/case in JS?