# How to do PigLatin in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Can somebody please help me with PigLatin? I'm trying to solve is problem here and my code works most of the time but I can't make some parts of it work.

For example when I give a string to the function like `quiet` or `square`, I want the function to take the `qu` part as 1 letter. So `quiet` would be `ietquay` and `square` would be `aresquay`..

Would it also be possible to make it work when I give it a long string with multiple words? Do the function on every word in the string basically..

My code so far:

```
const piglatin = string => {
    let firstVowel = string.match(/[aeiou]/);
    let firstPosition = string.indexOf(firstVowel);

    if (firstPosition > 0) {
        return string.slice(firstPosition) + string.slice(0, firstPosition) + 'ay';
    }

    return string + "ay";
}
```

Comment: how should single letter words like 'a' be converted ? what about two letter words 'is' ? you should specify all those in your question.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306899/pig-latin-translator-javascript any help?