# Why won't this iterate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I am trying to make this Pig Latin function (I just started coding 3 weeks ago, so go easy on me), and I can't figure out why I can't get the array made from `.split(' ')` and then iterated through to join back again.  In the output I only get the first word.  The code is below:

```
function pigLatin(str) {
  let str1 = str.split(' ')
  for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    if (str1[i].length <= 1) {
      return str1[i]; 
    }
    else {
      let first = str1[i].substring(0,1);
      let word = str1[i].substring(1);
      str = word + first + 'ay';
      return str
    }
  }
}

console.log(pigLatin("This is a test"));
```

Keep in mind that I was considering adding regex and more else if statements, but I can't even get this to work yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pig Latin Translator - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306899/pig-latin-translator-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You're `return`ing too early. You should be adding each word to an array, and at the end of your loop you should concatenate the words in the array to form a new string which you should return. See my comments for how I altered your code:

```
function pigLatin(str) {
let r = [] // The array to build
let str1 = str.split(' ')
for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
  if (str1[i].length <= 1) {
    r.push( str1[i] );  // Add to end of array
  }
  else {
    let first = str1[i].substring(0,1);
    let word = str1[i].substring(1);
    str = word + first + 'ay';
    r.push(str) // Add to end of array
    }
  }
  return r.join(' ') // Join strings in array and return new string
}

console.log(pigLatin("This is a test"));
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, I realized I wasn't using push as I was driving home, but this really helped.  Thanks for the reply.